# Using Apple Push Notifications Console with Safari Web Push?

Tags: safari, web-push, safari-push-notifications

I'm developing a website using standard Web Push, but my notifications aren't coming through on Safari. I'm trying to debug this.

Is it possible to use the Apple Push Notifications Console to debug/analyze Safari Web Push deliverability?

I can't figure out how to use it for web push. When I login and try to use the Push Notification Console, it asks me to choose an "app." But for standard Safari 16+ Web Push, there is no "app," no "Website Push ID", etc. that I register with Apple. So how can I use the Push Notification Console for this?

Apple's documentation does strongly imply that it should work.

[Sending web push notifications in web apps and browsers](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/sending_web_push_notifications_in_web_apps_and_browsers):

> To resolve an error, address the issue and resend your push notification request. For more information about the factors that impact the delivery of a push notification, see [Viewing the status of push notifications using Metrics and APNs.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/viewing_the_status_of_push_notifications_using_metrics_and_apns)

And that page is all about the Push Notification Console. So it must be possible somehow, right?